# How can I call notify() in Java without blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading

Are there a replacement for the follow Java code that will not block? I want only ping a possible waiting thread. I does not want change any on a possible thread that is already in the monitor.

```
synchronized( monitor ) {
    monitor.notify();
}
```

Comment: `notify()` never blocks, your title is misleading. :)

Comment: I would assume he means blocking other threads via synchronized.

Comment: You do need to block to be able to notify :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore instead of monitor. A binary semaphore can have the same use as a synchronize block:

```
private final Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(1, true); // binary: only 1 permit
....
try {
    sema.acquire();   // blocks till permit is available
    try {
        // critical section code
        ....
    } finally {
        sema.release();   // release permit
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    ....
```

You can check the state of the semaphore with the following methods:

```
sema.availablePermits()  // 1 if no threads in critical section
sema.getQueueLength()    // number of threads blocked waiting on acquire
sema.getQueuedThreads()  // list of threads blocked waiting on acquire
```

Comment: In case we want to discard all blocked threads, Is it good approach to interrupt all threads in a collection returned by sema.getQueuedThreads()?

Answer (score 2):

The point of the notify is to let other threads that are waiting on the monitor know that they can try to obtain it.  Only the current owner of the monitor can send the notify to indicate that they are done with it.

To own the monitor, you are obviously blocking any other thread.  That is the purpose of the monitor after all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [ReentrantLock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) solve your problem? For example

```
class X {
   private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   // ...

   public void m() {
     lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
     try {
       // ... method body
     } finally {
       lock.unlock()
     }
   }
 }
```

Additionally, you can do stuff like

```
lock.isLocked()
```

and

```
lock.tryLock()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try park/unpark with `LockSupport.getBlocker()`

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. You will get a "current thread not owner" if you try something like that.